# Animate text element by adding a class and animate it back to initial color by removing the class

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I don't want to give my element the color class for some reason (I just give it a class name to be able to select it but I want to have color classes not attached to the element)

How can I toggle between colors? I mean animate color from blue to red and animate again from red to blue...

Here is an ugly solution I have here, but I think there should be a better and cleaner way maybe using pure CSS like toggle a class, and when class is attached element is blue if it removes the element animates back to red...

```js
const text = document.querySelector(".myClass");

text.addEventListener("click", function (){
  
  if(text.classList.contains("changeBlue")){
     text.classList.add("changeRed");
     text.classList.remove("changeBlue");
  } else if(text.classList.contains("changeRed")){
     text.classList.add("changeBlue");
     text.classList.remove("changeRed");
  } else {
     text.classList.add("changeRed");
  }
  
  
})
```

```css
@keyframes changeRedAnime {
  from {color: blue}
  to   {color: red}
}

.changeRed {
  animation-name: changeRedAnime;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes changeBlueAnime {
  from {color: red}
  to   {color: blue}
}

.changeBlue {
  animation-name: changeBlueAnime;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.myClass {
  user-select:none;
  color:blue;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">This is a sample text.</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative is to store css class names in array and use some `index-access-increment-modulo` magic

**Example**

```js
const text = document.querySelector(".myClass");
const classList = text.classList;
const values = ["changeBlue", "changeRed"]
let it = 0;

text.addEventListener("click", function () {
  classList.remove(values[it++ % 2]);
  classList.add(values[it % 2]);
})
```

```css
@keyframes changeRedAnime {
  from {color: blue}
  to   {color: red}
}

.changeRed {
  animation-name: changeRedAnime;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes changeBlueAnime {
  from {color: red}
  to   {color: blue}
}

.changeBlue {
  animation-name: changeBlueAnime;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.myClass {
  user-select:none;
  color:blue;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">This is a sample text.</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is good JS in answer of @Józef Podlecki, but I'd like to improve your CSS as well. You don't need such massive constructions with `animation`. `transition: color .5s linear;` will be enough.

Or you can set some default color class from the beginning and then just toggle classes.

```js
const text = document.querySelector(".myClass");
text.addEventListener("click", function (){
  text.classList.toggle("red");
  text.classList.toggle("blue");    
})
```

```css
.myClass {
  user-select:none;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: color .5s linear;
}
.red {
  color: red; 
}
.blue {
  color: blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass blue">This is a sample text.</div>
```

Comment: Updated a bit. Look please.

Comment: would a ".myClass:not(red) {color:blue;}" also suffice, so only a single class needs to be toggled?

Comment: I think it will work as well. But you  you hvae a little mistake. ".myClass:not(.red) {color:blue;}". You forgota the dot before ''red"

Comment: ups, yes, the dot is missing, thanks for spotting this ... sadly no comment editing.